# Mapping over sequence with a constant

Tags: dictionary, clojure, functional-programming, constants, sequence

If I need to provide a constant value to a function which I am mapping to the items of a sequence, is there a better way than what I'm doing at present:

```
(map my-function my-sequence (cycle [my-constant-value]))
```

where my-constant-value is a constant in the sense that it's going to be the same for the mappings over my-sequence, although it may be itself a result of some function further out. I get the feeling that later I'll look at what I'm asking here and think it's a silly question because if I structured my code differently it wouldn't be a problem, but well there it is!

Answer (score 9):

In your case I would use an anonymous function:

```
(map #(my-function % my-constant-value) my-sequence)
```

Using a partially applied function is another option, but it doesn't make much sense in this particular scenario:

```
(map (partial my-function my-constant-value) my-sequence)
```

You would (maybe?) need to redefine my-function to take the constant value as the first argument, and you don't have any need to accept a variable number of arguments so using `partial` doesn't buy you anything.

Answer (score 9):

I'd tend to use partial or an anonymous function as dbyrne suggests, but another tool to be aware of is `repeat`, which returns an infinite sequence of whatever value you want:

```
(map + (range 4) (repeat 10))
=> (10 11 12 13)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way that I find sometimes more readable than `map` is the `for` list comprehension macro:

```
(for [x my-sequence]
   (my-function x my-constant-value))
```

Answer (score 1):

yep :) a little gem from the ["other useful functions"](http://clojure.org/other_functions) section of the api `constantly`

<s>(map my-function my-sequence (constantly my-constant-value))</s>

the pattern of (map compines-data something-new a-constant) is rather common in idomatic clojure. its relativly fast also with chunked sequences and such.

EDIT: this answer is wrong, but `constantly` and the rest of the "other useful functions" api are so cool i would like to leave the reference here to them anyway.

Comment: constantly returns a function, not a seq: `clojure.core/repeat

([x] [n x])
  Returns a lazy (infinite!, or length n if supplied) sequence of xs.`