# apply function to elements of collection with a constant argument

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mapping over sequence with a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190004/mapping-over-sequence-with-a-constant)

I'm trying to do the following (just an example):

```
(defn f [x param] ( 
  ; do something with "x" AND with "param"
  ))
(defn filtered-list [param] (map f ["a" "b" "c"]))
; called later as
(filtered-list 123)
; expected calls are: (f "a" 123), (f "b" 123) and (f "c" 123)
```

So, I need to find a way to pass `param` to `f`, being used by `map`. Is it possible in Clojure? This feature may also be known as ["functional closure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `partial` to create a curried function from f with param being passed

```
(defn f [param x] ( 
  ; do something with "x" AND with "param"
  ))

(defn filtered-list [param] (map (partial f param) ["a" "b" "c"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [partial](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/partial)?

```
(defn f [param x]  
    (str param \- x) ;; do something
)

(defn filtered-list 
    [param] 
    (map (partial f param) ["a" "b" "c"]))
```

You have to change the order of the parameters of `f`, though.